# Selecting records from multiple tables with counts

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen many similar posts but cannot seem to pair similar cases to my exact solution/needs.

I have data in 6 tables, and need to get a list of all cities from each table and the amount of records for each city along with it.

My current query:

```
(SELECT res.CITY FROM rets_property_res res) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT rnt.CITY FROM rets_property_rnt rnt) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT lnd.CITY FROM rets_property_lnd lnd) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT hir.CITY FROM rets_property_hir hir) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT cnd.CITY FROM rets_property_cnd cnd) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT mul.CITY FROM rets_property_mul mul) 
ORDER BY CITY ASC
```

I have tried many efforts to add the count but cannot get the syntax correct as I am not so great with mySql syntax.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking... some sample data might help to exemplify your problem.  However, my gut is already screaming that (from the superficial information you've shown so far) this schema appears to violate the [principle of orthogonal design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design).

Comment: Please, don't put the code in a long horizontal line: it's very hard to read.

Comment: Do you want the count of ALL records for each city or do you want a count of each city within each table? In other words if you have 2 occurrences of 'Smallville' in 1 table and 3 occurrences in another table do you want it to report 2 and 3 or do you want it to report 5?

Comment: getting all totals across all tables per name is sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i). When you need the count of rows based on a filed or fields you can use `Group by` on that field(s).

Now you want to know count of each table so you need a field that specify table names like `tName` and ...

With this you will have count of cities of each table

```
SELECT count(*) AS CNT, CITY, tName 
FROM (
    SELECT res.CITY ,'res' as tName 
    FROM rets_property_res res 
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT rnt.CITY,'rnt' as tName 
    FROM rets_property_rnt rnt
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT lnd.CITY,'lnd' as tName 
    FROM rets_property_lnd lnd
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT hir.CITY,'hir' as tName 
    FROM rets_property_hir hir
  UNION ALL
    SELECT cnd.CITY,'cnd' as tName 
    FROM rets_property_cnd cnd
  UNION ALL
    SELECT mul.CITY,'mul' as tName 
    FROM rets_property_mul mul
    ) as DT
Group by tName, CITY
ORDER BY CITY ASC
```

Comment: i want to select this as the answer however it was not returning the city name as well. I modified the first line to SELECT count(*) AS CNT,CITY, tName

Comment: @webfish if you want `CITY` in `Select` statement you should add it to `Group By` part too.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your whole query in a sub-query then you can calculate your COUNT() off those results:

```
SELECT CITY, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  (SELECT res.CITY FROM rets_property_res res) 
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT rnt.CITY FROM rets_property_rnt rnt) 
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT lnd.CITY FROM rets_property_lnd lnd) 
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT hir.CITY FROM rets_property_hir hir) 
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT cnd.CITY FROM rets_property_cnd cnd) 
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT mul.CITY FROM rets_property_mul mul) 
)
GROUP BY CITY
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will give you the count of each city from each table

```
(SELECT res.CITY, resDup.res_count FROM rets_property_res res 
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(CITY) res_count FROM rets_property_res GROUP BY CITY) resDup ON `resDup`.`CITY` = `res`.`CITY`
    ) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT rnt.CITY, rntDup.rnt_count FROM rets_property_rnt rnt
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(CITY) rnt_count FROM rets_property_rnt GROUP BY CITY) rntDup ON `rntDup`.`CITY` = `rnt`.`CITY`
    ) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT lnd.CITY, lndDup.lnd_count FROM rets_property_lnd lnd
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(CITY) lnd_count FROM rets_property_lnd GROUP BY CITY) lndDup ON `lndDup`.`CITY` = `lnd`.`CITY`
    ) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT hir.CITY, hirDup.hir_count FROM rets_property_hir hir
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(CITY) hir_count FROM rets_property_hir GROUP BY CITY) hirDup ON `hirDup`.`CITY` = `hir`.`CITY`
    ) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT cnd.CITY, cndDup.cnd_count FROM rets_property_cnd cnd
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(CITY) cnd_count FROM rets_property_cnd GROUP BY CITY) cndDup ON `cndDup`.`CITY` = `cnd`.`CITY`
    ) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT mul.CITY, mulDup.mul_count FROM rets_property_mul mul
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(CITY) mul_count FROM rets_property_mul GROUP BY CITY) mulDup ON `mulDup`.`CITY` = `mul`.`CITY`
    ) 
    ORDER BY CITY ASC
```

Let me know if there is any issue

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.